# "Device already has a newer version" error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

So my previous version of my app had in the gradle file

```
    versionCode 17
    versionName "0.0.28"
```

But I wanted to update my app to use [the system in this article](https://medium.com/@manas/manage-your-android-app-s-versioncode-versionname-with-gradle-7f9c5dcf09bf), like so:

```
def versionMajor = 0
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 29
    ...
    versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 100 + versionPatch
    versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
```

Now given the above code, you'd expect versionCode to come out as 29, but what happens is strange -- when I try to update it from version 17, it gives the error `"Installation failed since the device already has a newer version of this application."` BUT when I do the same as above, but just write `versionCode 29`, I don't get that error at all.

Why would I get that error when 29 is produced by code but not when I hardcode the number?

Comment: delete the build folders and clean build your app

Comment: @SahilManchanda submit this as an answer and I'll accept it. For some reason it's working now. I tried it on my emulator about 5 times just to make sure before posting this question, but suddenly I look like a goof -- I didn't even have to delete the build folders or clean-build the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete the build folders and then clean build your app